# Помогите выявить ошибку. Все логи есть... кроме тестов. АВЛ-дерево [СИ]

Tags: c, дерево

Дoбpый вeчep!

Преподаватель дал мне задание на создание программы - работы с АВЛ-деревом

Я её написал, собственно вот код

```
/*
 Программу продготовил: Буренков Игорь (М8О-206Б-17)

 Вариант: АВЛ-дерево

 Коды ошибок:

 1** - процесс ввода
 2** - процесс сотрировки
 3** - процесс вывода

 *42 - Ошибка выделения памяти
 *43 - Ошибка перевыделения памяти
 *50 - Ошибка ввода

 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> // Для контроля вылетов за границы
#include <math.h>   // Для округления
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


////////////////////////////////////////////////
// НАСТРОЙКИ
////////////////////////////////////////////////
unsigned short int StringLength = 257; // Длина строки (256 символов + '\0')
unsigned short start_init = 4;        // Кол-во инициируемых элементов по умолчанию
float step_init = 1.5;                // Кол-во эл-ов добавляемых в дин. массив за раз
bool debugstoper = false;             // Пауза при отладке


 // Структуры
struct incmd {
    char cmdindex;                      // Сама комманда
    char *cmdword;                      // Текстовый параметр
    unsigned long long int *cmdint;     // Числовой параметр
};

struct avlleaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева
    char key[257];                                // Ключ
    unsigned long long int llupar;                // Числовой параметр
    long long int height;                         // Высота
    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок
    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок
};

// Основные Функции (сигнатуры)
char InputFiller(struct incmd**); //Функция для заполнения массива
char TreeShell(struct incmd**);   //Функция для выполнения комманд

////////////////////////////////////////////
//     ФУНКЦИИ РАБОТЫ С АВЛ - ДЕРЕВОМ     //
////////////////////////////////////////////

// Освобождение памяти
void MakeEmpty(struct avlleaf* tree){
 if(tree == NULL) return;
 MakeEmpty(tree->left);
 MakeEmpty(tree->right);
 free(tree);
}

// Вычисление высоты
long long int Height(struct avlleaf* tree){
 if (tree == NULL) {
     return -1;
 }else {
     return tree->height;
 }
}

// Вычисление максимального элемента
long long int MaxLL(long long int a, long long int b){
 if (a > b) {
     return a;
 } else {
     return b;
 }
}

// Small Right Rotation
struct avlleaf* SRR(struct avlleaf* tree) {
 struct avlleaf* tmp;
 tmp = tree->left;
 tree->left = tmp->right;
 tmp->right = tree;
 tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
 tmp->height =  MaxLL(Height(tmp->left), tree->height)+1;
 return tmp;
}

// Small Left Rotation
struct avlleaf* SLR(struct avlleaf* tree){
 struct avlleaf* tmp;
 tmp = tree->right;
 tree->right = tmp->left;
 tmp->left = tree;
 tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
 tmp->height =  MaxLL(Height(tree->right), tree->height)+1 ;
 return tmp;
}

// Full Left Rotation
struct avlleaf* FLR(struct avlleaf* tree){
 tree->right = SRR(tree->right);
 return SLR(tree);
}

// Full Metal Alchemist
struct avlleaf* FRR(struct avlleaf* tree){
 tree->left = SLR(tree->left);
 return SRR(tree);
}

// Добавление листа
struct avlleaf* InsertLeaf(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[257], unsigned long long int llupar){
  unsigned short int i;
    if (tree == NULL) {
       printf("OK\n");
       tree         = malloc(sizeof(struct avlleaf));
       tree->llupar = llupar;
       tree->height = 0;
       tree->left   = NULL;
       tree->right  = NULL;
       for (i = 0; i < 257; i++) {
        tree->key[i]   = key[i];
       }
    } else
    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) {
       tree->left = InsertLeaf(tree->left, key,  llupar);
       if ((Height(tree->left)) - (Height(tree->right)) == 2){
           if (strcmp(key, tree->left->key) < 0) tree = SRR(tree);
           else tree = FRR(tree);
       }
    } else
    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) {
       tree->right = InsertLeaf(tree->right, key, llupar);
       if ((Height(tree->right)) - (Height(tree->left)) == 2){
           if (strcmp(key, tree->right->key) > 0) tree = SLR(tree);
           else tree = FLR(tree);
       }
    } else {
        printf("Exist\n");
        return tree;
    }

    tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
    return tree;
}

// Поиск минимального листа
struct avlleaf* FindMinL(struct avlleaf* tree){
 if(tree == NULL) return NULL;
 else if(tree->left == NULL) return tree;
 else return FindMinL(tree->left);
}

// Поиск максимального листа
struct avlleaf* FindMaxL(struct avlleaf* tree) {
 if(tree == NULL) return NULL;
 else if(tree->right == NULL) return tree;
 else return FindMaxL(tree->right);
}

// Удаление листа из дерева
struct avlleaf* DeleteLeaf(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[257]){
  struct avlleaf* temp;
  unsigned short int i;

  // Нет совпадений
  if (tree == NULL){
   printf("NoSuchWord\n");
   return NULL;
  }

  // Поиск элемента
  if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) tree->left = DeleteLeaf(tree->left, key);
  else if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, key);

  // Иначе элемент найден - обрабатываем случаи
  // Многодетный элемент
  else if((tree->left != NULL) && (tree->right != NULL)){
    temp = FindMinL(tree->right);
    tree->llupar = temp->llupar;
    for (i = 0; i < 257; i++) {
        tree->key[i]   = temp->key[i];
    }
    tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, tree->key);
  }
  // Один ребенок (2й - нулловый)
  else {
    temp = tree;
    if(tree->left == NULL)    tree = tree->right;
    else if(tree->right == NULL) tree = tree->left;
    free(temp);
    printf("OK\n");
  }

  // Если tree стул нуловым - выходим (все ок)
  if(tree == NULL) return tree;

  // Иначе...
  tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;

  // Проверка на нарушение баланса
  // Если удалили левый узел
  if(Height(tree->left) - Height(tree->right) == 2){
            if(Height(tree->left->left) - Height(tree->left->right) == 1)
                return SLR(tree);
            else
                return FLR(tree);
  }
  // Если удалили правый узел
  else if(Height(tree->right) - Height(tree->left) == 2){
            if(Height(tree->right->right) - Height(tree->right->left) == 1)
                return SRR(tree);
            else
                return FRR(tree);
  }

  // Итог
  return tree;
}

// Получить баланс
int GetBalance(struct avlleaf* tree){
        if (tree == NULL) return 0;
        else return Height(tree->left) - Height(tree->right);
}

// Вставка чистого дерева
struct avlleaf* InsertLeaf_clean(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[257], unsigned long long int llupar){
  unsigned short int i;
    if (tree == NULL) {
       tree         = malloc(sizeof(struct avlleaf));
       tree->llupar = llupar;
       tree->height = 0;
       tree->left   = NULL;
       tree->right  = NULL;
       for (i = 0; i < 257; i++) {
        tree->key[i]   = key[i];
       }
    } else
    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) {
       tree->left = InsertLeaf_clean(tree->left, key,  llupar);
    } else
    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) {
       tree->right = InsertLeaf_clean(tree->right, key, llupar);
    } else {
        return tree;
    }

    tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
    return tree;
}

// Печать дерева
void PrintMe(struct avlleaf* tree, unsigned long long int lvl){
  unsigned long long int i;
  if(tree == NULL) return;
  PrintMe(tree->right, lvl+1);
  for (i = 0; i < lvl; i++) {
    printf("\t");
  }
  printf("%llu", tree->llupar ); printf("\n");
  PrintMe(tree->left, lvl+1);
}

// Сохранение дерева
void SaveTree(struct avlleaf* tree, FILE * file){
  if(tree == NULL) return;

  fwrite(tree->key, 1, sizeof(tree->key), file);
  fwrite(&tree->llupar,  sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);

  SaveTree(tree->right, file);
  SaveTree(tree->left , file);
}

// Загрузка дерева
struct avlleaf* LoadTree(struct avlleaf* tree, FILE * file){
  char key[257];
  unsigned long long int llupar;
  // Читаем ключ - значение
  while (feof(file) == 0){
   fread(key, 1, sizeof(tree->key), file);
   fread(&llupar, sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);

   tree = InsertLeaf_clean(tree, key, llupar);
  }
 return tree;
}

// Поиск элемента
void PrintID(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[257]){

    if (tree == NULL) {
       printf("NoSuchWord\n");
    } else {

      if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) {
         PrintID(tree->left, key);
      } else
      if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) {
         PrintID(tree->right, key);
      } else {
         printf("OK: ");
         printf("%llu", tree->llupar);
         printf("\n");
      }
    }
}



////////////////////////////////////////////
//         Основной "движок"              //
////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    // Создадим массив ввода
    struct incmd *incmd_dynmass;  // Дин. массив структур
    unsigned short int log_error; // Код ошибки [см. в начале]

    // Считываем ввод комманд
    log_error = InputFiller(&incmd_dynmass);
    if (log_error != 0){
      return 100 + log_error;
    }

    //Выполняем комманд
    log_error = TreeShell(&incmd_dynmass);
    if (log_error != 0){
      return 100 + log_error;
    }

    // ОТЛАДКА
    if (debugstoper == true)    system("pause");

    // Выход
    return 0;
}


// Функция ввода комманд
char InputFiller(struct incmd **incmd_dynmass) {

    // Переменные
    unsigned long long int initcount = 0; // На сколько элементов выделен массив
    char tmpchar;                         // Переменная для ввода первого параметра сообщения
    unsigned short int ticker;                          // Для цикла for

   // Инициализация структуры
    *incmd_dynmass = malloc(start_init * sizeof**incmd_dynmass);
    // Обработка ошибки памяти
    if (*incmd_dynmass == NULL) {
       return 42;
    }
    (*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long int));
    // Обработка ошибки памяти
    if ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint == NULL) {
       return 42;
    }
    (*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint[0] = 0; //Обнуляем количество элементов
    initcount = start_init;

  // Непосредственное считывание данных
   while ((scanf("%c", &tmpchar) >= 1)){
     // Отладка [Удалить на продакшене]
     if (tmpchar == '*') {
       debugstoper = true;
       break;
     }
     // Если кол-во свободных ячеек закончилось
     if (initcount == ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint[0])+1) {
       if (initcount*step_init <= ULLONG_MAX) {
         initcount=floor(initcount*step_init);
         *incmd_dynmass = realloc(*incmd_dynmass, initcount * sizeof **incmd_dynmass);
         if (*incmd_dynmass == NULL) { // Ошибка перевыделения памяти
           return 43;
         }
       }
     }

     // Непосредственное добавление комманды
     switch (tmpchar){
      case '+':
      // Добавление элемента (1-WORD-ULL)
        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 1;  // Указываем операцию

        // Выделение памяти
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdint =  malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long int));
        if (((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL)||(*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdint == NULL) {
           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти
        }

        // Считывание 2го параметра (WORD)
        if (scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword) < 1) {
          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода
        }

        // Перевод в нижний регистр
        for (ticker = 0; ticker < StringLength; ticker++) {
          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker] =
             tolower((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker]);
        }

        // Добавление знака окончания строки
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[StringLength-1] = 0;

        // Считывание 3го параметра (ULL)
        if (scanf("%llu", &((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdint[0])) < 1) {
          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода
        }

        while (getchar() != '\n'){
          ticker++; // Заглушка
        }

        break;

      case '-':
      // Добавление элемента (2-WORD)
        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 2;  // Указываем операцию

        // Выделение памяти
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));
        if ((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL) {
           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти
        }

        // Считывание 2го параметра (WORD)
        if (scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword) < 1) {
          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода
        }

        // Перевод в нижний регистр
        for (ticker = 0; ticker < StringLength; ticker++) {
          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker] =
             tolower((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker]);
        }

        // Добавление знака окончания строки
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[StringLength-1] = 0;

        // Проход оставшееся строки
        while (getchar() != '\n'){
          ticker++; // Заглушка
        }

        break;

      case '!':
      // Добавление элементов (3-WORD) или (4-WORD)
        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов

         // Выделение памяти
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));
        if ((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL) {
           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти
        }

        // Выбор операции
        while ((tmpchar != 'S') && (tmpchar != 's')  && (tmpchar != 'L')  && (tmpchar != 'l')) scanf("%c", &tmpchar);
        if ((tmpchar == 'S')||(tmpchar == 's')) {
          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 3;  // Указываем операцию
        } else
        if ((tmpchar == 'L')||(tmpchar == 'l')) {
          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 4;  // Указываем операцию
        }
        scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword); // Сбрасываем до сл. параметра

        // Считывание 2го параметра (WORD)
        if (scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword) < 1) {
          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода
        }

        // Добавление знака окончания строки
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[StringLength-1] = 0;

        while (getchar() != '\n'){
          ticker++; // Заглушка
        }

        break;

      case '\n':
       // Пустая строка --> пропускаем
       break;

      default:
      // Добавление элементов (5-WORD)
        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов

        // Выделение памяти
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));
        if ((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL) {
           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти
        }

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 5;  // Указываем операцию

        // Добавление параметра WORD
        // Восстановление первого элемента
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[0] = tmpchar;
        tmpchar = getchar();
        ticker = 0;
        while ((tmpchar >= '0')&&(ticker < StringLength)) {
          ticker++;
          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker] = tmpchar;
          tmpchar = getchar();
        }

        // Перевод в нижний регистр
        for (ticker = 0; ticker < StringLength; ticker++) {
          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker] =
             tolower((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker]);
        }

        // Добавление знака окончания строки
        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[StringLength-1] = 0;

       break;
     }


   }

   // ОТЛАДКА
   /*
   for (initcount = 1; initcount <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; initcount++){
    printf("\n");
    printf("%i", (*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdindex);
    printf("\n");
   }

    for (initcount = 1; initcount <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; initcount++){
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdword);
    printf("\n");
   }

   for (initcount = 1; initcount <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; initcount++){
    printf("\n");
    if ((*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdint != NULL) {
     printf("%llu", (*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdint[0]);
    }
    printf("\n");
   }
   */

 return 0;
}


char TreeShell(struct incmd **incmd_dynmass) {

 // Переменные
 unsigned long long int tmp1_ull, tmp2_ull; // Временные переменные
 char tmpkey[256];
 struct avlleaf *tree = NULL;
 FILE *file;


 //Цикл прхода по коммандам
 for (tmp1_ull = 1; tmp1_ull <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; tmp1_ull++) {
   //Проходимся по коммандам
    switch ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdindex) {
     case 1:
     // Ввод ключа
      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {
        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);
      }
      tree = InsertLeaf(tree, tmpkey, (*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdint[0]);
      break; // Выход
     case 2:
     // Удаление ключа
      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {
        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);
      }
      tree = DeleteLeaf(tree, tmpkey);
      break;
     case 3:
     // Сохранение дерева в файл
      // Ввод пути
      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {
        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);
      }
      // Попытка открыть файл
      file = fopen (tmpkey, "wb+");
      if (file == NULL){
        printf ("ERROR: Couldn't create file\n");
      } else
      {
        printf("OK\n");
        // Запись дерева
        SaveTree(tree, file);
      // Закрытие файла
        fclose (file);
      }
      break;
     case 4:
     // Загрузка файла
      // Ввод пути
      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {
        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);
      }
      // Загружаем файл
      file = fopen( tmpkey , "rb" );
      if (file == NULL){
       printf ("ERROR: FileSystem\n");
      } else{
       printf("OK\n");
       // Удаляем предыдущее дерево, если есть
       MakeEmpty(tree);
       tree = NULL;
       // Считываем значение и добавляем элемент
       tree = LoadTree(tree, file);
       // Закрываем файл
       fclose (file);
      }
      break;
     case 5:
      // Ищем элемент
      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {
        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);
      }
      PrintID(tree, tmpkey);
    }
 }
 // [ДЛЯ ОТЛАДКИ]
 //PrintMe(tree, 0);
 return 0;
}
```

Преподаватель, прежде чем смотреть лично, прогоняет программу в чекере.
Так вот, тесты для чекера неизвестны, но преподаватель скинул лог.

Ответ чекера:

```
Status:
Runtime error at test 04.t, got signal 14

    First 10 lines of failed test:
    + wtrttNwtwt 6356151351436705792
    + wtrttNwtw 11355346280444854272
    + wtrttNwt 6920329909665726464
    + wtrttNw 399671756802097152
    + wtrttN 11243149194066984960
    + wtrtt 5245798614692528128
    + wtrt 12751358511042461696
    + wtr 1814494297426624512
    + wt 9695799558577651712
    + w 3437433912018599936


    --
```

Лог, который скинул препод:

```
checker@checker:~/checked/da/burenkov-igor_bbccaa@ya.ru/2/2018.11.28.13.56.00/tmp/lb2$ ./lb2 < ../../last_test > out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
checker@checker:~/checked/da/burenkov-igor_bbccaa@ya.ru/2/2018.11.28.13.56.00/tmp/lb2$ gdb lb2 lb2.core 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-dragonfly".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.dragonflybsd.org/>...
Reading symbols from /home/checker/checked/da/burenkov-igor_bbccaa@ya.ru/2/2018.11.28.13.56.00/tmp/lb2/lb2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New process 1]
Core was generated by `lb2'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x0000000000401053 in SRR ()
(gdb) where
#0 0x0000000000401053 in SRR ()
#1 0x00000000004011ef in FLR ()
#2 0x0000000000401819 in DeleteLeaf ()
#3 0x00000000004015c6 in DeleteLeaf ()
#4 0x00000000004015c6 in DeleteLeaf ()
#5 0x00000000004015c6 in DeleteLeaf ()
#6 0x00000000004015c6 in DeleteLeaf ()
#7 0x000000000040160a in DeleteLeaf ()
#8 0x000000000040160a in DeleteLeaf ()
#9 0x0000000000402a7d in TreeShell ()
#10 0x0000000000401e04 in main ()




---
```

Мне нужно выяснить, при каких тестах появляется ошибка?
В чем она заключается?
Как ее можно устранить (опционально)?

Cпaсибo!

P.S. Простите за кривокод, на Си редко пишу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при тестировании. Что означает "got signal 14"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912743/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-got-signal-14)

Comment: @PinkTux тот вопрос удален
Т.к. в нем нет лога

Comment: Здесь есть лог, которого нет в якобы дубликате. Также в дубликате мне требовался ответ на вопрос, что за ошибка, а здесь - где она и при каком условии.

Comment: я посмотрел код и главное, что я не увидел - само дерево.. Зато почему-то увидел массив в main.

Comment: Да, и поповоду "обработки ошибки выделения памяти" - не эффективно и бесполезно, особенно в маленькой программе. Память может не выделиться только если вся память уже забита, а в вашем случае - это утечка памяти из-за которой комп просто напрочь зависнет. Лучшее, что может сделать программа в случае, если не была выделена память - это скрашануться.

Comment: в нодах (который у вам почему-то tree) avl дерево нужно хранить не высоту, а баланс и балансировать дерево относительно него. И я что-то невижу у вас в коде как вы идете от вставленно элемента вверх по дереву балансируя ноды

Comment: Я храню в нодах не баланс, а высоту, как на хабре

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch так и не понял, в чем проблема... Мне нужно, чтоб чекер схавал, поэтому и на память тоже исключения добавил (ибо положено). Храню высоту, а не баланс, т.к. так удобней, а высота сильно не вырастает. А вот первый массив в main - там комманды лежат, для управления деревом. Само дерево во 2й функции TreeShell.

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG ну храните вы восоту - окей, а как балансировать его собрались? Я у вас вообще этого не вижу. А на хабре много чего - и не обязательно хорошего (а кое что и древнее говна мамонта)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Баланс - это разница высот детей (Я могу ошибаться - так что поправьте, если не прав). Я при добавлении ищу разницу и основываясь на ней применяю вращения (см. InsertLeaf), вращения же выполняются в функции SRR, SLR, FLR, FRR (Smal Right Rotation, например)

Comment: Я юзал этот пост: https://habr.com/post/150732/

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG ага, выполнили вы поворот для ноды, которую только что вставили - а дальше что? Ничего, что баланс родительской ноды тоже мог поменяться?

Comment: А также код отсюда: https://gist.github.com/harish-r/097688ac7f48bcbadfa5

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я вроде это учел: tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;

Comment: А т.к. это рекурсия - то пересчитывается вся ветка до этого элемента